# Line numbers and go to line

Tags: python, if-statement, line, portable-python

I have a quiz and on the final round, I would like it to end if it gets an incorrect value

I have an `if` loop, but I would like my final `else` values to have a **go to line *line number*** code as it is a long code. In order to use this function, how could I view line numbers (I use *Portable Python Scripter*).

````
print("PLEASE NOTE: Answers are case-sensitive, so start all answers with a capital letter.")
print("Getting full marks (5/5) in each round will allow you to complete the next round.")
#==============================================================================
singer = input("Who is your favourite singer?")
if singer == "Harry Styles" or "Harry":
    print("Great choice!")
else:
    print(singer +" is good, but Harry Styles is better")
#==============================================================================
ans = input("Do you want to do a Harry Styles quiz?")
if ans == "No":
    print("How rude!")
elif ans == "Yes":
#==============================================================================
    q1 = input("What boyband was Harry Styles in?")
    if q1 == "One Direction":
        print("Correct!")
        score = 1
    elif q1 == "1D":
        print("Correct!")
        score = 1
    elif q1 == "White Eskimo":
        print("Correct!")
        score = 1
    else:
        print("Incorrect")
        score = 0
#==============================================================================
    q2 = input("What is Harry's birthday (write in format dd/mm/yyyy)")
    if q2 == "01/02/1990":
        print("Correct!")
        score = score + 1
    else:
        print("Incorrect")
#==============================================================================
    q3 = input("What is Harry's favourite film?")
    if q3 == "Love, Actually":
        print("Correct!")
        score = score + 1
    elif q3 == "Love Actually":
         print("Correct!")
         score = score + 1
    else:
        print("Incorrect")
#==============================================================================
    q4 = input("What war film did Harry star in?")
    if q4 == "Dunkirk":
        print("Correct!")
        score = score + 1
    else:
        print("Incorrect")
#==============================================================================
    q5 = input("What is Harry's mum's first name?")
    if q5 == "Anne":
        print("Correct!")
        score = score + 1
    else:
        print("Incorrect")
#==============================================================================
    if score < 5:
        ps = str(score)
        print("You achieved " + ps)
    if score ==  5:
        print("Well done! You got everything correct!")
        print("Entering quickfire round...")
#==============================================================================
        score =  0
        print("Instructions:")
        print("Your score has been reset to 0")
        print("If you get a question incorrect, you will lose 1 point")
        print("If you achieve below 0, you wil end the game.")
#==============================================================================
        while score <= 0:
            qf1 = input("What is Harry's 2nd album called?")
            if qf1 == "Fine Line":
                print("Correct")
                score = score + 1
                print(score)
            else:
                print("Incorrect")
                score = score - 1
                print(score)
#==============================================================================
            qf2 = input("How old was Harry when he went on the X-Factor?")
            if qf2 == "16":
                print("Correct")
                score = score + 1
                print(score)
            elif qf2 == "Sixteen":
                print("Correct")
                score = score + 1
                print(score)
            else:
                print("Incorrect")
                score = score - 1
                print(score)
#==============================================================================
            qf3 = input("Finish the quote: 'This is a family show. _________?'")
            if qf3 == "Or is it?":
                print("Correct")
                score = score + 1
                print(score)
            elif qf3 == "Or is it":
                print("Correct")
                score = score + 1
                print(score)
            else:
                print("Incorrect")
                score = score - 1
                print(score)
#==============================================================================
            qf4 = input("What is Harry's middle name?'")
            if qf4 == "Edward":
                print("Correct")
                score = score + 1
                print(score)
            else:
                print("Incorrect")
                score = score - 1
                print(score)
#==============================================================================
            qf5 = input("What is Harry's blood type?'")
            if qf5 == "B+":
                print("Correct")
                score = score + 1
                print(score)
            elif qf5 == "B positive":
                print("Correct")
                score = score + 1
                print(score)
            else:
                print("Incorrect")
                score = score - 1
                print(score)
#==============================================================================
        if score < 0:
            print("GAME OVER!")
#==============================================================================
        if score > 0:
            if score < 5:
                ps = str(score)
        if score == 5:
            print("Wow, that's full marks! Well done!")
#==============================================================================
            print("Entering Death Row...")
            score =  0
            print("Instructions:")
            print("Your score has been reset to 0")
            print("If you get a question incorrect, you will end the game")
#==============================================================================
            d1 = input("What characer does Harry play in the MCU (Marvel Cinematic Universe)?")
            if d1 == "Starfox" or "Eros":
                print("Correct!")
                score = score + 1
#==============================================================================
                d2 = input("What does Harry say the best thing a girl can wear is?")
                if d2 == "A smile" or "Smile":
                    print("Correct!")
                    score = score + 1
#==============================================================================
                    d3 = input("What did Harry dress up as for 2021's 'Harryween'?")
                    if d3 == "Alice" or "Alice in Wonderland" or "A clown" or "Clown":
                        print("Correct!")
                        score = score + 1
#==============================================================================
                        d4 = input("Which singer does Harry have a crush on?")
                        if d4 == "Adele":
                            print("Correct!")
                            score = score + 1
#==============================================================================
                            d5 = input("How many nipples does Harry have?")
                            if d5 == "Four" or "4":
                                print("Correct!")
                                score = score + 1
#==============================================================================
                                if score == 5:
                                    print("Oh ma gawd! You got everything correct!")
                                    print("I think you dropped this []")
                                    print("Get your certificate here: [https://drive.google.com/file/d/1k-PJEQmqW_rv56vSId0PDo6etuC_up_G/view]")
#==============================================================================
                            else:
                                ps = str(score)
                                print("Incorrect")
                                print("You achieved " + score)
                        else:
                            ps = str(score)
                            print("Incorrect")
                            print("You achieved " + score)
                    else:
                        ps = str(score)
                        print("Incorrect")
                        print("You achieved " + score)
                else:
                    ps = str(score)
                    print("Incorrect")
                    print("You achieved " + score)
            else:
                print("Incorrect")
#==============================================================================
else:
    termination = (ans.upper())
    print("ERROR! CANNOT COMPUTE! UNKNOWN VARIABLE: [" + termination +"]")
    print("TERMINATING QUIZ!") ```
````

Comment: There is no goto in Python. There are functions and loops instead.

Comment: `singer == "Harry Styles" or "Harry"` should be `singer in ("Harry Styles" , "Harry")`, because actually it's always True (as it is wronge code)

Comment: There are ways to rewrite this code so that it won't be so long and require so much duplication in the first place.  The general strategy I'd take would be to put all the questions in a list, iterate through until there's a wrong answer, and then `break`.  That's essentially what you're trying to do with the `goto`, but easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using loops and functions can help you make this code quite a bit shorter and eliminate a lot of the need for copy+pasted if/else.  Here's a quick rewrite of the initial quiz section with the outline of a `main()` function to give you the idea:

```
def first_round():
    """Ask the first round questions, return cumulative score."""
    score = 0
    for question, answers in [
        ("What boyband was Harry Styles in?",
            {"One Direction", "White Eskimo"}),
        ("What is Harry's birthday (write in format dd/mm/yyy)",
            {"01/02/1990"}),
        ("What is Harry's favourite film?",
            {"Love, Actually", "Love Actually"}),
        ("What war film did Harry star in?",
            {"Dunkirk"}),
        ("What is Harry's mum's first name?",
            {"Anne"}),
    ]:
        if input(question) in answers:
            print("Correct!")
            score += 1
        else:
            print("Incorrect")
    return score


def main():
    # do intro stuff here

    score = first_round()
    if score < 5:
        print(f"You achieved {score}")
        return  # Game over!

    print("Well done! You got everything correct!")
    print("Entering quickfire round...")

    # continue on with score = quickfire_round()...


main()
```

Putting code in functions means that when it's time to end, you can just `return` and have the rest of the function continue at the outer level of indentation instead of having to go into deeper and deeper nested `if/elif/else` statements to continue the program.  Using loops (like in the `first_round` function above) means that you don't need to copy and paste the same code over and over either.

Taking the pattern above and applying it to the Death Round, we might have something like:

```
def death_round():
    """Ask the death round questions -- first wrong answer ends it!"""
    score = 0
    for question, answers in [
        ("What characer does Harry play in the MCU (Marvel Cinematic Universe)?",
            {"Starfox", "Eros"}),
        ("What does Harry say the best thing a girl can wear is?",
            {"A smile", "Smile"}),
        ("What did Harry dress up as for 2021's 'Harryween'?",
            {"Alice", "Alice in Wonderland", "A clown", "Clown"}),
        ("Which singer does Harry have a crush on?",
            {"Adelete"}),
        ("How many nipples does Harry have?",
            {"Four", "4"}),
    ]:
        if input(question) in answers:
            print("Correct!")
            score += 1
        else:
            print("Incorrect")
            return score  # sudden death!
    return score
```

Note the `return` in the "Incorrect" case, which is the one way this function differs from `first_round`, and is also what makes it so you don't need a `goto` or five different nested `else` statements to keep track of the five different times you might end the game -- as soon as there's a wrong answer, the function returns, whereupon `main` can look at the final score and do different things based on its value.

One more thing to think about as you work on your quiz -- right now it's very sensitive to exact phrasing *and* casing, even though you've provided multiple correct options.  For example:

```
What does Harry say the best thing a girl can wear is?Her smile
Incorrect
```

Here's one approach to fixing it that will make it so that any answer which contains the word "smile" will be accepted, regardless of case:

```
for question, answers in [
    ("What does Harry say the best thing a girl can wear is?",
        {"smile"}),
    ("What did Harry dress up as for 2021's 'Harryween'?",
        {"alice", "clown"}),
]:
    answer = input(question).lower()
    if any(a in answer for a in answers):
        print("Correct!")
    else:
        print("Incorrect")
```

```
What does Harry say the best thing a girl can wear is? Just a smile
Correct!
What did Harry dress up as for 2021's 'Harryween'? A fabulous clown
Correct!
```

Comment: tysm! This helps so much!